# Setting up angularjs constant based on query parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular constant which is pointing to webservice end point

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('ws_url', 'http://localhost:9000')
```

I want to pass the ws_url as query parameter and set the constant value to that value.

So if I call my server like `http://localhost?ws_url=localhost:8000` I should be set the constant as `loclahost:8000` than default value.

How can I do that?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking.  Can you try to clarify please?  Maybe give an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Updated the question. Is it still not clear?

Comment: If you mean pass a value as a query string and set the constant to the value in the query string, you don't want to use `constant` for that.

It's called a constant because it doesn't change.  Store the value in a service.
Constants are for when you want to bootstrap the app with certain static data.

Comment: I want to keep the information static till the point we reload the app. So its kind of constant throughout the app and not dynamically changing.

Comment: You just need to be able to access the value from anywhere in the app?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to put it in $rootScope.

Comment: @neolivz4ever take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a query param and if you want to access that value across all other controller, then rather than using `$rootScope` better go for a `factory` or `service` like as shown below

if you want to give static url then use

```
var searchQueryParams = $location.url('http://localhost?ws_url=localhost:8000'); 
searchQueryParams.$$search.ws_url; // gives you the ws_url query param value
```

if you want to get the dynamic url then use

```
var searchQueryParams = $location.search();
searchQueryParams.ws_url  // gives you the ws_url query param value if url is http://localhost?ws_url=localhost:8000
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9k8rxo5z/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerOne"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo"></div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ControllerOne', function ($location, WebServiceValues) {
    var searchQueryParams = $location.url('http://localhost?ws_url=localhost:8000'); 
    WebServiceValues.setUrlParam(searchQueryParams.$$search.ws_url);
    console.log('ControllerOne getUrlParam:',WebServiceValues.getUrlParam())
});

app.controller('ControllerTwo', function (WebServiceValues) {
    console.log('ControllerTwo getUrlParam:',WebServiceValues.getUrlParam())
});

app.factory('WebServiceValues', function () {
    var webServiceUrlParam
    return {
        setUrlParam: function (urlParam) {
            webServiceUrlParam = urlParam;
        },
        getUrlParam: function () {
            return webServiceUrlParam;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) Tweaked a little it worked perfectly fine for my case.